# Выполнить плавную анимацию svg

Tags: css, svg, svg-animation

```css
.spinner {
    fill: none;
    stroke: rgb(255 43 43);
    stroke-width: .7;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-dashoffset: 100.5;
    stroke-dasharray: 100.5;
    animation: spinner 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

    @keyframes spinner {
  0% {stroke-dasharray: 0, 100; stroke-dashoffset: 0}
  50% {stroke-dasharray: 65, 35; stroke-dashoffset: -35}
  100% {stroke-dasharray: 65, 100; stroke-dashoffset: -100.5}
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" style="height: 200px">
<circle class="spinner" cx="5" cy="5" r="2.3"><animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" dur="5s" values="0 5 5;360 5 5" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform></circle></svg>
```

По размерам подогнал, а вот выполнить плавную анимацию не удается. Собственно, как выполнить так чтобы анимация была плавной и хотя бы небольшая часть оставалась полоски оставалось, а то пропадает слвсем

Comment: Есть много готовых svg лоадеров, скачайте что нибудь, посмотрите как там всё устроено, сделайте под себя. Или просто используйте готовый. К чему все эти муки?)

Comment: Необходимо именно под этот размер 10 на 10, в таком масштабе.  Возможно ли сохранить данную анимацию, но при этом избавиться от тега animateTransform, перенести данную анимацию в css. И возможно ли выполнить так, чтобы данная анимация работала в не зависимости от значения параметра r="2.3"